# How to properly use dblink_build_sql_insert (postgreSQL)

Tags: postgresql, dblink

I cannot find an example of how it's supposed to work for a table with only one PK field.

My attempt looks something like this:

```
CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS dblink;

select dblink_build_sql_insert('table_name'::text, '1'::int2vector, 1::int2, '{"12345"}'::text[], '{"column1", "column2", "column3", "column4"}'::text[]);
```

It keeps trowing the error "target key array length must match number of key attributes". As I see it I told him that the number of key attributes is 1 and the target key array length has 1 item. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

If I read the examples right, I think you need to do something like

```
select dblink_build_sql_insert(
     'table_name'::text, 
     '1'::int2vector, 
      1::int2,  -- num of pkey values
      '{"12345"}'::text[], -- old pkey 
     '{"column1"}'::text[] -- new pkey
);
```